# Find angle $x$ in the circle below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

In the figure, A, B, C, and D are points of tangency . Determine x. (S:$x=60^o$)

[image]

I try

$\angle FUG = x+3(\beta+\theta)$

$\angle CFE = 180-4\theta-x (I)$

$\angle BGE = 180-4\beta - x(II)$

$(I)and(II): \angle CFE -\angle BGE = 4(\beta-\theta)$

$\angle BFC \cong \angle UGC$

[image]

Comment: Did you try to take advantage of the fact that lines through BF and CG go through the center of the circle?

Comment: @Moti Yes but I didn't finish

Comment: Stretch EB and EC to get additional angels.

Comment: @Moti If you have a solution could you post it?

Comment: This is a very nice problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use $t,s$ instead of $\theta,\beta$ for an easy typing. We are starting with the following situation, which copies the OP figure, and marks some more angles relevant for a first step:

[image: stackexchange 4708162]

Let $u$ be the common measure of the arcs
$
\overset\frown{AB} =
\overset\frown{BC} =
\overset\frown{CD}
$.
Then the complement of $u$, i.e. $90^\circ-u$, as built in $F$ and in $G$ gives:
$$
\frac{4s+x}2=u=\frac{4t+x}2\ ,\
$$
which implies $s=t$. (Above, $4s+x$ is the exterior angle in $G$ for$\Delta BEG$, so it is the sum of the interior angles in $B,E$, which were given.)
From now on we will keep only $s$, use it also instead of $t$. The sum of the angles in the quadrilateral $OAED$ is $360$, which gives also $x$ in terms of $s$ from $180^\circ=3u+(t+x+s)=3\left( 90^\circ - \frac{4s+x}2 \right)+(2s+x)$, we extract first $4s+x$, then $x$:
$$
x = 180^\circ -8s\ .
$$
Then we can compute other angles in terms of $s$: By symmetry, $U$ is on $EO$, and $EO\perp FG$. The angle $\widehat{FEU}$ is $\frac 12(t+x+s)=90^\circ-3s$, so $\widehat{EFG}=\widehat{EGF}=3s=\widehat{EBG}$, the quadrilateral $EFBG$ is cyclic, so $EFBCG$ cyclic.

Before we conclude, it is maybe a good didactic idea to show the situation so far. For a given $s$ we have then the following picture, some of the properties of the given picture have been used, but evidently, some of them are missing:

[image: mathematics stackexchange 4708162 second figure]

(A lot of things do not fit, $EFL$, $EGM$ are not tangent $FUC$, $GUB$ are not tangent to the circle $O$. How to conclude quickly?)

From $EFBCG$ cyclic we obtain $\widehat{FBE}=\widehat{FCE}=3s$. Recall that we want a right angle
$$
90^\circ=\widehat{FBG}=\widehat{FBE}+\widehat{EBG}=3s+3s=6s
\ .
$$
This determines $s=15^\circ$, and then $x=180^\circ-8s=60^\circ$.

$\square$

---

---

*Note:* So far we have shown that if such a configuration exists, then $s=15^\circ$ and $x=60^\circ$. Well, the problem assumed that it exists, and we may stop here. But let us prove that the only one possible configuration exists indeed. We do so from the second figure. If $s=15^\circ$, then conversely $\widehat{FBG}=3s+3s=90^\circ$, so $BG$ is tangent to the circle $(O)$ in $B$. Why is $EFL$ tangent to this circle, too?

[image: mathematics stackexchange 4708162 third picture]

We compute angles of $\color{forestgreen}{30^\circ}$ in $L,U,M$ as shown in the picture. Let $O$ be the intersections of the lines $FB$ and $GC$. These are the perpendicular bisectors of the segments $LU$, $UM$. The reflection of $FUC$ w.r.t. $FBO$ is $FL$ first, and it is also tangent (in the reflection of $C$) to the circle. In same manner, $GM$ is a tangent, too.

Comment: Thanks for help. Excellent, one question: what guarantees that EO $\perp FG$?

Comment: In the first place i am using $EO\perp FG$ we have $s=t$ (and $x=180^\circ-8s$). And now i have to say something about the kind of problems we have. Usually, in the books that i had some many years ago, the geometric constructions were given in order, the points, lines, circles, ... came one by one, at each point having all other objects well defined. Your questions often come with a situation where "everything is given", and sometimes it is hard to figure out a possible order. In the mean time i've got the "taste" of the problems, they do not explicitly introduce anything. But on the other...

Comment: ... on the other side, the "rules of the game" are also different. We do assume tacitly for instance that the given figure exists. (And that it is more or less unique, because implicitly the problem wants us to determine something.) Now we take this figure "as it is" and apply a reflection denoted by a prime that interchanges the tangents $EA$ and $ED$. The circle is kept in place, $A=D'$ and $D=A'$, then $B,C$ correspond since $s=t$, so $B=C'$ and $C=B'$, and finally $F,G$ are determined by $OB$ and $OC$, so $F=G'$ and $G=F'$. So $FG$ is perpendicular on the axis of symmetry $EO$.

Comment: Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In figure we have:

$\beta=\theta=15^o$

$\overset {\large\frown}{GH}=2\theta=30^o$

$FE||GI||HK$

$\overset {\large\frown}{GH}=\overset {\large\frown}{GF}=\overset {\large\frown}{IK}=\overset {\large\frown}{EI}$

$\angle EBU=\angle ECU=\frac{\overset {\large\frown}{FH}+\overset {\large\frown}{EI}=60+30}2=45^o$

$\angle EHK=\frac{\overset {\large\frown}{EK=FH=60}}2=30^o$

J is mid point of arc IK. so :

$\angle JOK=15^o$

So the rays of angles LKD and JOK must be perpendicular, that is $EL\bot HL$ at H, so we have:

$x=\angle HEL=90-30=60^o $

We may also say:

$AE\bot ED\Rightarrow x=90-2\times 15=60^o$

Update: Another approach:

Considering your figure we have:

$GB=GD\Rightarrow \overset {\large\frown}{BC}=\overset {\large\frown}{CD}$

similarly:

$FA=FC\Rightarrow \overset {\large\frown}{BC}=\overset {\large\frown}{BA}$

$ \Rightarrow \overset {\large\frown}{BA}=\overset {\large\frown}{CD}= \overset {\large\frown}{BC}=\frac{90}3=30^o$

$\Rightarrow \widehat{BOC}=30^o$

Also if mirror the construction about AD you find:

$\widehat {COD}=2\theta$

$\widehat {BOA}=2\beta$

Now in quadrilateral EBOC we have:

$x+ (\widehat{EBC}=90+3\theta)+( \widehat{ECO}=90+3\beta)+ [(\widehat{BOC}=90-2(\theta+\beta)=30]=360$

Or:

$x+3(\theta +\beta)=150$

Also $x+(\theta+\beta)=90$

which finally gives $x=60^o$

Comment: How do you conclude that $theta$ and $beta$  measure  $15^o$?

Comment: @petaarantes, You may consider this as a particular case, where $\beta=\theta$, then they must be $15^o$ if the answer should be $60^o$. In fact there can be more solutions.

Comment: But this time you are starting from the answer that they are worth 15 degrees. I can show that $\theta= \beta$ but I still can't show that they are worth 15 degrees. I have one more equation left to figure out to solve the system

Comment: @petaarantes, If the construction is symmetric about OE, then there can be a point like  I' which is the mirror of I about OE and is mid point of arc EF, that is we have $\overset {\large\frown}{HK}=180^o$ divided by 6 which menas $\overset {\large\frown}{GH}=30^o$ and $x=15^o$.

Comment: On an unrelated note: how did you draw such a figure?

Comment: Thansks for help